# Multiple Notes Simultaneously - Overflow Error

Tags: python, audio

I have successfully generated .wav files in python of sine waves at different frequencies.
If I wish to generate harmonies, for example, a C major tirade, am I supposed to add the each sine wave of the individual notes together?

When adding 2 notes together, say C and G, the program creates the correct harmony. When I attempt to add a third note though, there is an overflow error. How might this be successfully accomplished.

**The Code:**

I am placing the data for the sine waves into an array of signed short integers.

```
wave = array.array('h')
```

And then adding multiple waves togeather to generate the harmonies.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    wave1[i] += wave2[i]
```

This works!

But when I add a third array, (wave3), it overflows.

This is because the signed short integer has reached its maximum. I am working with a 16 bit rate. Is the problem simply that the bit rate is too low? When creating complex audio with lots of harmonies, does the bit rate simply need to be much higher? Have I approached the problem in the absolute wrong direction?

[**Full Source**](http://pastebin.com/BzwC6XuR)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the byterate. You just have to normalize the values so that they fit properly. I've rewritten your code a bit so it uses lists at first, then arranges all the values from 0 to 32767, taking into account the volume, and puts it into the array.

```
def normalize(nmin, nmax, nums): #this could probably be done a bit shorter
    orange = max(nums)-min(nums)
    nrange = nmax-nmin
    nums = [float(num)/orange*nrange for num in nums]
    omin = min(nums)
    nums = [num-omin+nmin for num in nums]
    return nums

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data, data2, data3 = [], [], []

    data.extend(create_data(getTime(1), getFreq('C', 4)))
    data2.extend(create_data(getTime(1), getFreq('Bb', 4)))
    data3.extend(create_data(getTime(1), getFreq('G', 4)))

    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] += data2[i]
        data[i] += data3[i]

    data = array.array('h', [int(val) for val in normalize(0, 32767*VOLUME/100, data)])

    write_wave(data, int(len(data)/SAMPLE_RATE))
    winsound.PlaySound('output.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```